# How to fix error in switch statement in C?

Tags: c, terminal, syntax-error, cs50

I am coding in sandbox.cs50.io and I am persistently getting the same error. This is my code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#include <cs50.h>


int main(void)

{

int x = get_int( );

switch(x)

    {

    case1: printf("One!\n");

           break; 

    case2: printf("Two!\n");

           break; 

    case3: printf("Three!\n");

           break;

    default: printf("Sorry!\n");

    break;

    }

}
```

THE ERROR:

```
clang -fsanitize=signed-integer-overflow -fsanitize=undefined -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c11 -Wall -Werror -Wextra -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-unused-parameter

 -Wno-unused-variable -Wshadow    switch.c  -lcrypt -lcs50 -lm -o switch

switch.c:6:18: **error: too few arguments to function call, at least argument 'format' must be specified**

**int x = get_int( );**

        ~~~~~~~  ^

/usr/include/cs50.h:82:1: note: 'get_int' declared here

int get_int(const char *format, ...) __attribute__((format(printf, 1, 2)));

^

1 error generated.

<builtin>: recipe for target 'switch' failed

make: *** [switch] Error 1
```

Comment: I started with
 #include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>

Comment: You should have showed the declaration of `get_int()`. But this is just a simple typo IMO, not passing the format needed to interpret the number from the text, or passing any text to be interpreted in the first place...

Comment: can you share more details? for example what is cs50, link to the tutorial if you are following one etc.

Answer (score 0):

You need a format string :  x = get_int("%d");

Answer (score 0):

You have entered case1, case2 and case3. They should be case 1, case 2, case 3, with a space I mean. Try it.